# Java programming with uml

Tags: java, uml, emf, xmi, umbrello

I'm a java developer new with uml modeling. I wanna create a complete web application (backend+db+jms+security +ui) deployable to an application server by using only UML. Despite I didn't understand what really is meta-modeling I started using Umbrello, visual paradigm and eclipse emf.
I've read just a little about omg's xmi standard.
So supponing to have an xmi file I didn't understand how to generate java code. Eclipse emf for example would generate "strange" java code. 
Do I need to 
write my own xmi parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to write my own xmi parser?

No.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse EMF generator generates code for saving and loading your model, so there is no need to write your own parser or serializer.

EMF allows you to generate a maximum of four different plugins for a defined model:

- Model: The model contains all entities, packages and factories to create instances of the model.
- Edit: The edit plugin contains providers to display a model in a UI. For example, the providers offer a label for every model element, which can be used to display an entity showing an icon and a name.
- Editor: The editor plugin is a generated example editor to create and modify instances of a model.
- Test: The test plugin contains templates to write tests for a model.

This is a good article if you need any help with EMF:
What every Eclipse developer should know about EMF. 
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/